# How to properly match a sequence using regular expression in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string, `s="abaaaababbb".`

I am using findall method and I want to know all the occurrences of `(ab)+`.
The code that I am using is:

```
import re
s = "abaaaababbb"
x = re.findall("[ab]+",s)
print(x)
```

Output:
`['abaaaababbb']`

Instead I wanted output like:
`['ab' , 'abab']`

How to write the correct regular expression for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you mentioned in your question (`(ab)+`) is almost correct.

You just need to make the capturing group a non-capturing one:

```
(?:ab)+
```

This is because `findall` will return all the *groups* (as opposed to all the matches) if you have any capturing groups in the regex.

Comment: What is a capturing group I don't understand and what if in place of 'ab', I want to match '()'

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee you’d still need a non-capturing group. You’d also need to escape the parentheses, so `(?:\(\))+`. You should really learn more about regex first.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee See [the regex reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/5133585)

Comment: Thanks alot, I found what I was looking for (y)